# Why is the function $F(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t^{1/3}(t+1)}dt$ defined in $(-1,+\infty)$?

Tags: integration, functions

I know that the domain of $f(x)=\frac{1}{t^{1/3}(t+1)}$ is $D=(-\infty, -1)\cup (-1,0) \cup (-1, +\infty)$, but I can't understand why $F(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t^{1/3}(t+1)}dt$ is defined in $(-1,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens with the integrand when you integrate

$$\int_{1}^{-2}\dfrac{1}{t^{1/3}(t+1)}dt?$$

Think about the singularity for $t=-1$.